# Convergence in distribution

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, convergence, central-limit-theorem

For a statistic $T_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^nY_i - \frac{1}{a}$.
Prove directly (without CLT) that scaled and appropriately shifted version of $T_n$ converges in distribution to $N(0,1)$.

[EDIT]

$f(y|a,b)=ae^{-a(y-b)}$ for $ y\geq b$

How should I approach the problem?

[EDIT]

I thought that if I could find the expected value and variance of $T_n$ and then represent it in $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$

for $f(y)$, $E[Y] = b+1/a$, $Var [Y] = 1/a^2$

For $Tn$,

$Var[T_n] = Var[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^nY_i - \frac{1}{a}]$ = $a^2/n$

$E[T_n] = E [\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^nY_i - \frac{1}{a}] = b$

[EDIT]

$M_X(t)=\frac{ae^{bt}}{(a-t)}$

How should I go from here?

Comment: (i) Please read the [self-study tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) - what have you tried? (ii) note that, as given, the above statement is false. For example, if $Y_i$ is Cauchy, no scaled and shifted version of $T_n$ converges to $N(0,1)$. Did you leave out part of the question?

Comment: @Glen_b Yes I missed to write the distribution of $Y_i$. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Exploit the fact, that characteristic function convergence is equivalent to convergence in distribution. I.e. show that

$$E\exp(i\tilde T_{n}t)\to \exp(-t^2/2),$$

for any $t$, where $\tilde T_n$ is appropriately scaled and shifted version of $T_n$. Another useful fact is that the characteristic function of the sum of independent random variables is the product of the corresponding characteristic functions of the summands.